# Calculate weekly retention in google big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a big table in google big query and there are two columns on which I want to perform retention:-

```
Date                           user
2021-02-03 08:35:07 UTC        foo@abc.com
2021-02-03 08:35:07 UTC        foo1@abc.com
2021-02-04 08:35:07 UTC        foo2@abc.com
2021-02-05 08:35:07 UTC        foo@abc.com
2021-02-03 08:35:07 UTC        foo1@abc.com
2021-02-10 08:35:07 UTC        foo@abc.com
2021-02-13 08:35:07 UTC        foo1@abc.com
2021-02-18 08:35:07 UTC        foo3@abc.com
2021-02-21 08:35:07 UTC        foo2@abc.com
2021-02-23 08:35:07 UTC        foo2@abc.com
2021-02-24 08:35:07 UTC        foo5@abc.com
2021-02-24 08:35:07 UTC        foo2@abc.com
```

I want to calculate retention on the below condition:-

percentage of unique users for week1 present in week2

percentage of unique users from week2 present in week3 and so on.

The desired out format will be:-

```
week2  week3   week4 
23%    56%     33%
```

I want to perform this on a time frame like one month or 6 months and whatever timeframe I choose the output should be in the above format.

I want a solution for Big Query but even a MySQL solution will help me.

Comment: Why the mysql/sql tags?

Comment: because the query is in sql/mysql only. even a mysql/sql solution will work for me.

Comment: OK, define a 'week'

Comment: starting 7 days is the first week and so on.

Comment: And (finally?), what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using big query.... but you can help me with any MysqL version...I will convert it

Comment: Please edit your question to include all this information within the body of the question. That way, you have a better chance of others seeing this information.

Comment: Is this for BigQuery or MySQL query?

Comment: BigQuery but even a MySQL solution will help me as I can convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
WITH leads AS (
      SELECT
        user,
        EXTRACT(ISOWEEK
        FROM
          `Date`) AS visit_week,
        EXTRACT(ISOWEEK
        FROM
          LEAD(`Date`) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY `Date`)) AS next_visit_week
         -- here you look the user's next visit and take the week. If the user is there the following week, next_visit_week = visit_week + 1
      FROM
        `your_project`.`your_dataset`.`your_table`)


SELECT
  visit_week+1 AS `week`,
  SUM(CASE 
        WHEN visit_week= next_visit_week-1 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END
    )/COUNT(DISTINCT user)*100 AS retention_pct
FROM
  leads
GROUP BY
  `visit_week`
```

For each week, you count the number of times the next visit of a user occurs the week following the current week (NB: it can only occur once for each user). You divide the total by the number of distinct users.

You therefore obtain the retention rate for the following week (hence the '+1' in the "visit_week+1 AS `week`").

Comment: NB: since you mention time frame of 6 months or less, I did not consider the year

Comment: Is there a way i can give my timeframe while querying....its never going to be too big but if I can say I want the result from this date to this date.

Comment: Of course, you just need to add the filter 
" WHERE `Date` BETWEEN "2021-01-01" AND "2021-03-31" " in the definition of the "leads" temporary table here

Comment: Hey Any idea how we can implement the same for daily retention. @Cylldby

Comment: Also its giving me retention starting week4 any idea why week 1 2 and 3 is not present

Comment: whay if I have to extract the day? will I use ISODAY?